# Function do not catches the exception when invoking async action

Tags: c#, .net

Please help, how do I make `DoAction` catch the exception when calling `Button_Click_1`?
I know about `Func<Task>` but in this case the `Button_Click` requires a `Task` to be returned but I do not need it. Is there some generic version of the `DoAction` that can work with async and non-async actions?

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoAction(() =>
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Non async");
    });
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoAction(async () =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Async");
    });
}

private void DoAction(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {

    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to await your asynchronous call.

Comment: just to call `async` is to *fire* and *forget* (no `await`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new async method that handles delegates of type `Func<Task>`. The `Task` object returned from async methods contains the exception. To catch it you have to use `await` which will wait for the task to complete and throw an exception if there was any.

```
        private async Task DoAction(Func<Task> action)
        {
            try
            {
                await action();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {

            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Also your method `Button_Click_1` should be async, because `DoAction` is async so usage would look like this:

```
        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await DoAction(async () =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Async");
            });
        }
```